# How do I sum() rows from another table on Order No from the first table?

Tags: sql-server, subquery, inner-join

trying to query

```
select  sh.[Salesperson], sh.[No], sh.[EstimatedHours], 
sum(sl.[ActualHoursStraightTime]), sum([ActualHoursOvertime])
from [Service Header Table] sh join [Service Line Table] sl

on sh.[No] = sl.[OrderNo]
```

the result keeps multiplying my EstimatedHours by the sum of ActualHoursStraightTime.

I'm not sure how to write this.
I also need to use a where clause for a column in the Service Line Table that shows "" or OT for Overtime or not.

Comment: Could you show some sample input data, the expected result, and the result you're getting instead?

Comment: I think you're just missing a `GROUP BY` clause, so you get each salesperson's hours instead of combining everyone.

Comment: I'll post results shortly.  Server is updating.  I will say, however, on [Service Header Table] there is only 1 row for each sh.[No] in the query. There are multiple entries for each sl.[OrderNo] in the [Service Line Table] for the different days that hours are logged by techs. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
select  
    sh.[Salesperson], 
    sh.[No], 
    sh.[EstimatedHours], 
    sum(sl.[ActualHoursStraightTime]), 
    sum([ActualHoursOvertime])
from [Service Header Table] sh 
join [Service Line Table] sl on sh.[No] = sl.[OrderNo] 
WHERE sl.Overtime = ''
    OR s1.Overtime = 'OT'
GROUP BY sh.[Salesperson], 
    sh.[No], 
    sh.[EstimatedHours]
```

Comment: select  
        sh.[Salesperson Code], 
        sh.[No_], 
        sh.[Est_ Hours], 
        sum(sl.[Quantity]) 
    from [CARDINAL INTEGRATED - LIVE$Service Header]sh
    join [CARDINAL INTEGRATED - LIVE$Service Line]sl on sh.[No_] =             sl.[Document No_] 
    WHERE sh.[Service Order Type] = 'INSTALL'
    
    GROUP BY sh.[Salesperson Code], 
        sh.[No_], 
        sh.[Est_ Hours]

Comment: This is my actual query.  It returns only four row when I add the where clause for 'install'.  There are many more than that which should be returned.  Quantity is all in the same column for straight time and overtime.  Another column in the Service Line table is populated with either '' or 'OT'.

Comment: Expected result:

Salesperson No Est. Hours Act. Hours ST Act. Hours OT Balance
DAVID  1001  16  5  1 10
ROB  1003  24  1  3 20
KEITH  1006  100  75  0 25
DAVID  1007  60  20  10 30